# Xamarin Notifications - workflow

Tags: c#, xamarin

i have no idea how is the workflow like.

Example if i have an app (calendar), where user select a event on 01 May 2018.

Do i save this date to my server database (sql) then have my backend script to loop through the all dates on the database, so if EventDate = Today then send a notification? Or is this an old school method?

Can it be done with Firebase that if EventDate = Today then send out notification?

Or possible to completely avoid using of server and using local notification (alarm manager) but is there a limit of how many events i can add?